# Troubleshooting 'can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple' error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

when I try to extend the django admin user. I got the following error.

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

this is my models.py class

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

User.add_to_class('age', models.BooleanField(default=False))

class Employee(models.Model):

  user=models.OneToOneField(User)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
  designation=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email=models.CharField(max_length=100)    
  role=models.CharField(max_length=10)  
  project=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  task=models.CharField(max_length=50)
  avatar = models.ImageField("Profile Pic", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)



def __unicode__(self):

    return self.name


def ensure_profile_exists(sender, **kwargs):
if kwargs.get('created', False):
    Employee.objects.create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))

post_save.connect(ensure_profile_exists, sender=User)
```

this is my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
 UserAdmin.list_display += ('age')
 UserAdmin.list_filter += ('age')
 UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('age',)
```

I need to add one filed called age to the django admin user, for example first name ,last name ,email and age in personal info. please someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change these lines to have comma after `'age'`

```
UserAdmin.list_display += ('age')
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('age')
```

as

```
UserAdmin.list_display += ('age',)
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('age',)
```

Otherwise python evaluates `('age')` to `'age'` rather than tupple.

You have done this appropriately in third line `UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('age',)`

Comment: ya. now it sloves that error. instead of that now it gives me a another error telling that "no such column: auth_user.age". what should I do for that?

Comment: @Lahiruzz, I'm not sure your way of adding `age` to `User` model is correct or not. I suggest to post another question regarding that, with details.